# I get an error when I am trying to create a table and I can't figure why

Tags: mysql, sql

I try to create 3 simple tables but I get an error for line 8 and I can't figure out why.

```sql
CREATE TABLE Customers(
    CustomerID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    CustomerName VARCHAR(200),
    Email VARCHAR(200),
    Age INT
)

CREATE TABLE Products(
    ProductID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    Title VARCHAR(200),
    Price INT
)

CREATE TABLE Orders(
    OrderID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    CustomerID INT,
    FOREIGN KEY(CustomerID) REFERENCES Customers(CustomerID),
    ProductID INT,
    FOREIGN KEY(ProductID) REFERENCES Products(ProductID),
    Quantity INT,
    OrderDate DATETIME
)
```

And I get the error:

```sql
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE Products(
    ProductID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    Title V' at line 8
```

Any ideas what's wrong ? It's a simple table creation.

Comment: (1) You have a MySQL error so I added the tag.  (2) The code is fine.  Here is a fiddle:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f475d35449cc146b7d7c28e4cab524de.  You can try putting a semicolon after the table definitions.

Comment: use `;` after create table statments:

Comment: And don't store 'age'

Comment: I can't believe I forgot the semicolon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is okay. You have to add semicolons (;) at the end of each SQL statement.

```
CREATE TABLE Customers(
    CustomerID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    CustomerName VARCHAR(200),
    Email VARCHAR(200),
    Age INT
);

CREATE TABLE Products(
    ProductID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    Title VARCHAR(200),
    Price INT
);

CREATE TABLE Orders(
    OrderID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    CustomerID INT,
    FOREIGN KEY(CustomerID) REFERENCES Customers(CustomerID),
    ProductID INT,
    FOREIGN KEY(ProductID) REFERENCES Products(ProductID),
    Quantity INT,
    OrderDate DATETIME
);
```

Online Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cbf746e/2/0

Update
As [Strawberry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1529673/strawberry) mentioned in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55088025/i-get-an-error-when-i-am-trying-to-create-a-table-and-i-cant-figure-why/55088126#comment96921982_55088025), do not use age as a column. Use Date of birth instead. Using the Date of Birth, you can calculate the age.

```
DateOfBirth DATE
```